# No Value for one or more required parameters

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I have this SQL query

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [tblStudent]![LastName] & ', ' & [tblStudent]![FirstName] & ' ' & [tblStudent]![MiddleName] AS FullName," & _
" tblGrade.FirstGrading, tblGrade.SecondGrading, tblGrade.ThirdGrading, tblGrade.FourthGrading," & _
" Avg(b.GradeValue) AS AverageGrade" & _
" FROM ((((tblGrade INNER JOIN tblEnrolment ON tblGrade.EnrolmentID=tblEnrolment.EnrolmentID)" & _
    " INNER JOIN tblStudent ON tblStudent.StudentID=tblEnrolment.StudentID)" & _
    " INNER JOIN tblSubjectOffering ON tblSubjectOffering.SubjectOfferingID=tblGrade.SubjectOfferingID)" & _
    " INNER JOIN tblSubject ON tblSubject.SubjectID=tblSubjectOffering.SubjectID)" & _
    " INNER JOIN tblSection ON tblSection.SectionID=tblSubjectOffering.SectionID" & _
" WHERE tblSection.SectionTitle='" & s(0) & "' AND tblSubject.SubjectID='" + s2(0) + "'" & _
" GROUP BY [tblStudent]![LastName] & ', ' & [tblStudent]![FirstName] & ' ' & [tblStudent]![MiddleName], tblGrade.FirstGrading, tblGrade.SecondGrading, tblGrade.ThirdGrading, tblGrade.FourthGrading" & _
" ORDER BY [tblStudent]![LastName] & ', ' & [tblStudent]![FirstName] & ' ' & [tblStudent]![MiddleName]"
```

And this code gives me a runtime error "No value for one or more required parameters".

Answer (score 2):

My hunch is Access thinks `b.GradeValue` is a parameter because there is no table name or alias for `b`:

```
Avg(b.GradeValue) AS AverageGrade
```

I suggest you `Debug.Print` the completed `SELECT` statement, or write it to a text file, then test it as a new query in the Access query designer.  When it asks you to supply the parameter value, it also shows you the *"name"* of whatever it thinks is the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Very difficult to offer suggestions with only a SQL statement, out of context with your other code and objects.

As it stands, I see two main potential problems.  First is that you have `Avg(b.GradeValue)` but there is no reference to the `b` table elsewhere in the command.  For this, you would need to remove the `b` or make sure the reference is valid.

Second, you have two variables, `s()` and `s2()` that could be returning invalid or null data.  You may want to debug this step and check the values each of these holds before letting it proceed, then fix the problem in the other part of your code if one is bad.

Comment: I don't understand your third paragraph.  When `s(0)` and `s2(0)` are Null, the resulting SQL will be `WHERE tblSection.SectionTitle='' AND tblSubject.SubjectID=''`  That may not be the `WHERE` he wants, but it should not cause the missing parameter problem.

Comment: You are probably right.  In my effort to remove all the VBA/Access remnants (so it would look like normal SQL for me to analyze) I must have removed the extra single quotes.  Still, it's possible that invalid values there are causing problems, which may relate to this... that's the problem with having such isolated snippets in a question.

Comment: I'm not really sure what's going on here, either.  I suspect the OP would be better off creating and testing a parameter query in Access, saving it as a named query, and then executing that query from VB6 with parameter values supplied at runtime.